Why wont ubuntu boot from my SSD?
Recently a client of mine requested a unique system. He wanted a secure system with Mac anon, OS encryption and Windows VM and various other programs and applications. I configured the system with Rufus and initially loaded the latest version of Ubuntu and started installing the software on it. It took me a very long time as some libraries were missing which is normal.
I finally finished. I tested the system and even the software I installed on the Windows VM and it all looked good. I rebooted to see if it booted OK and tested all the software to make sure it persisted. Next i was I was ready to deliver the system to my client and then when we went to boot it up as I pressed Esc to boot from USB and the white font on the side didn't appear as usual when you boot up.
From here it just froze. I can't get to recovery mode, I can't get to BIOS, and I can't get to boot settings. As soon as I take the SSD out it will start up and I can choose any other these options.
Additionally I flashed Ubuntu again on just a USB this time and it's booting fine. As I said the SSD booted fine before as well many times and I don't see how anything could have got corrupted. I have a HP 15-dy5027ca laptop I got my client to get. I am stumped. I enabled and disabled secure boot and I don't know what to do next. Nothing I can think of is working. The SSD that I am working on is the 2 TB MyPassport. The system config took me 3 days and I really would like to try and see if I can fix this before I reformat the disk and start over again. I also think perhaps I need to try a different drive as this may happen again.

HP is one of the least friendly to Linux. When you install grub, it uses efibootmgr to install entry into UEFI and reset boot order to have Ubuntu first. HP seem to not recognize some change by efibootmgr. You have to change boot order in HP system settings (not HP boot menu) And if drive is added to new system, you need to reinstall grub or use efibootmgr to add boot entry. I may add entry, but not change boot order. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. What version of Ubuntu?

Does this answer your question? No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority
